# When dragging an object with rigidbody2D it passes through colliders (walls)

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine

Ok, so I'm making this game where the user can drag a ball around the screen, but it's not supposed to leave the play area. I'm getting the [following problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d4dU91QqpiU) though, when I push it towards the colliders it bounces back, and if I push too hard it simply goes off screen (I need to make it do not go off screen. the user is free to drag it all over the place, but within the screen of course).

any tips on how I could solve this issue?

Here is the code for dragging which I'm using:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CircleManager : MonoBehaviour {


        private bool dragging = false;

        private Vector3 screenPoint;
        private Vector3 offset;

        // Pressionando
        void OnMouseDown()
        {
                dragging = true;
                screenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position);
                offset = gameObject.transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z));
        }

        // Arrastando
        void OnMouseDrag()
        {
                Vector3 cursorPoint = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z);
                Vector3 cursorPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(cursorPoint) + offset;

                //i tried with both below.
                //transform.position = cursorPosition;
                transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().MovePosition(cursorPosition);
        }

        // Soltando
        void OnMouseUp()
        {
                dragging = false;
        }


}
```

Thanks!

Comment: *"when I push it towards the colliders it bounces back"* what exactly are you expecting it to do?

Comment: I'm expecting it to simply do not go through the wall, sorry for the lack of clarity! I need it to just collide and stay there, not allowing the player to drag it off the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to do something like,

```
if( transform.position.x > xMaxPos )
{
    transform.position.x = new Vector3( xMaxPos, transform.position.y, transform.position.z );
}
```

You could set up for each min and max. Then when you create the xMaxPos variables, create them like:

```
[serializeField]
private float xMaxPos;
```

That way they will appear in the inspector and you can tweak their values as you please.  You could also throw in an offset that's the width of the ball i.e.

```
transform.position.x = new Vector3( xMaxPos - transform.localscale.x/2, transform.position.y, transform.position.z );
```

Comment: It worked almost perfectly! I had to use a transform.position (without the .x) and make a few other calculations, like getting the circle's radius and stuff, but it's great now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `velocity`

```
public class CircleManager : MonoBehaviour {


    private bool dragging = false;

    private Vector3 screenPoint;
    private Vector3 offset;

    public float speed = 5.0f;

    // Pressionando
    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        dragging = true;

        Vector3 cursorPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(ToDepth(Input.mousePosition, transform.position.z));

        offset = gameObject.transform.position - cursorPosition;
    }

    // Arrastando
    void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        Vector3 cursorPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(ToDepth(Input.mousePosition, transform.position.z)) + offset;

        Vector3 direction = (transform.position - cursorPosition).normalized;
        transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = direction * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    // Soltando
    void OnMouseUp()
    {
        dragging = false;
    }

    Vector3 ToDepth(Vector3 value, float depth)
    {
        return new Vector3(value.x, value.y, depth);
    }
}
```

Few things to note:
You don't have to write out `gameObject.transform.position` i see you did that a few times, as well as calling `transform...` directly. Its both the same thing, so you don't need the `gameObject` part.

Also your getting the `screenPoint` of the `transform`, then using the `z` value of that later on, which doesn't really make much sense to me.

Anyways, i don't see why this shouldn't work for you, i haven't tested it though.